# Sourdough starter and long term feeding

Tags: sourdough, sourdough-starter

I have a sourdough starter that I started about 3-4 months ago with bread flour and it's done really well. I am not baking a lot right now and would like to refrigerate it knowing that I need to feed it at least once a week. Can I feed it with some rye flour and bread flour?  I'd like to add some rye flour to the starter to keep it happy.  Would appreciate some guidance. I mostly make rye bread but I do make other types that use bread flour and a mix of whole wheat and rye. 
thanks.  I tried to find this answer in the search but couldn't find it.

Comment: What kind of flour did you use in the past? By bread flour, do you mean “wheat”?

Comment: I used King Arthur's " bread flour".  It's a white flour with higher protein content than all purpose but similar to all purpose

Answer (score 2):

A well-established starter will be fine in the refrigerator, even (in my experience) if you go well beyond weekly feedings. You could also freeze it, though I have not done that myself. No matter what my feeding schedule, or length of storage, I usually plan for a few days of counter-top feeding and revival before baking, just to ensure peak activity.  I've used all sorts of flour combinations.  For the home baker, it makes little difference, so yes...you can use all rye or a combination of rye and wheat.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I really appreciate it.